# Plone Search: get method to pass via URL to another site

Tags: overriding, plone, plone-4.x, viewlets

I am using Plone 4.3 and the diazo bootstrap theme and want to use the site-search-form to pass the searchterms including two search-options to another site (catalog) via get method.

To achieve this I have modified the plone.searchbox template and changed some content of it:

```
<div id="portal-searchbox"
     i18n:domain="plone"
     tal:define="navigation_root_url view/navigation_root_url;
                 search_input_id view/search_input_id;">

<form id="searchGadget_form" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://www.thecatalogadress.net/opensearch">

        <div class="LSBox">               
        <input name="LOCATION"
               type="hidden"
               value="HAGENBIB" />

        <input name="SG1.SG.HAGENBIB:SGHagenvk"
               type="hidden"
               value="on" />

        <input name="QUERY_alAL"
               type="text"
               size="18"
               value=""
               title="Finden"
               class="searchField" />

        <input class="searchButton"
               type="submit"
               value="search"
               i18n:attributes="value label_search;" />

        <div class="LSResult" id="LSResult"><div class="LSShadow" id="LSShadow"></div></div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

By now the search term is passed, but the two input-options are not introduced in the URL thus the query in the catalog doesn't work.

The result I need as URL is http://www.thecatalogadress.net/opensearch?LOCATION=HAGENBIB&SG1.SG.HAGENBIB:SGHagenvk=on&QUERY_alAL=test

As I am new to plone I wanted to ask for a hint, where to look at or what to change in order to add the two input-options to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably forgetting to add the proper ZCML directives for the override on the template take place.

Take a look at this tutorial on [Overriding Viewlets](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/more_view_examples.html).